# Need help on the windows 10 icon

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have an Acer Aspire One netbook which has Windows 7 starter. I have done the recent Windows updates, and says my windows 7 is all up to date. My dad has the same netbook but received the "Windows 10 icon at the bottom tray". My question is, why haven't I received the icon yet through the Windows updates? Which file contains that KB3035583?

Answer (score 0):

> If you don’t see the Get Windows 10  app on your PC, it might be
>   because:
>
> 1. Your device isn’t up-to-date with at least Windows 7 SP1 or Windows
>      8.1 Update.
> 2. Windows Update is turned off or is not set to received updates
>      automatically.
> 3. You’ve blocked or uninstalled the necessary Windows Update
>      functionality.
> 4. Your device is not running genuine Windows.
>
> Running Windows Update and installing any available updates will fix
>   the first three issues. Need more help? Go to our Windows Community
>   Forum.
>
> PCs that we determine cannot run Windows 10 will not see the Get
>   Windows 10  app before July 29, 2015. After July 29, 2015, we’ll
>   enable the icon in the system tray. This is to help ensure that you
>   can easily check your PC’s compatibility if you choose.
>
> If your device is managed as part of a school or business network,
>   please check with your IT administrator about upgrading to Windows 10.

[**Source:**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing), in particular "[Quote](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion". I've fixed your answer this time, please remember to do this in future. Thanks.